# Nested map function on parsed JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I am receiving a JSON data from database which is
 `[{"table_cols":["id","stud_name","stud_school"]}]`.

```
 console.log("Response is: " + resp._bodyText); {/*Response is: [{"table_cols":["id","stud_name","stud_school"]}]*/}

         let parsedData = JSON.parse(resp._bodyText);
         console.log(parsedData) //Object
        this.setState({...this.state,cols_of_sel_tab:parsedData})


        for(let i=0; i<this.state.cols_of_sel_tab.length;i++)
        {
            cols = [];
            console.log(this.state.cols_of_sel_tab[i])
            let cols = this.state.cols_of_sel_tab[i]
            console.log("WOW")
            for (let j = 0; j<cols.length; j++){
                console.log(cols[j])
            }
        }
```

Output: {table_cols: Array(3)}
WOW

Expected: To iterate through the inner for loop 
Desired output is: id, stud_name,stud_school

Tried: using forEach instead of inner for loop
Error: ...\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\YellowBox.js:82 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

I need help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State updates [**are asynchronous**](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). If you want to loop through the data you've received right then, use `parsedData`, not `this.state.cols_of_sel_tab`.

Separately, never do this:

```
this.setState({...this.state,cols_of_sel_tab:parsedData});
```

If you're setting state based on your current state, you must not pass in an object; instead, you must pass in a callback function that uses the state it receives as an argument (see the linked docs for details).

But in this case, you don't need the `...this.state` at all, so it would be fine if you just did this:

```
this.setState({cols_of_sel_tab:parsedData});
```

...and then (again) looped through `parsedData` not `this.state.cols_of_sel-tab`.

---

Separately, you have a problem with `cols`: You're trying to use it in a block before it's declared with `let`. If you'd really run that code, it would have failed with an error saying `cols` is not defined (because you cannot access an identifier declared with `let` or `const` within a block prior to the declaration, even if it exists in an outer scope).

Comment: I am sorry to say, I have looped on the state and it worked perfectly fine. And about updating the state, I have to use a callback function with prev state as the parameter. Please, Correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: @SwethaG: *"I have looped on the state and it worked perfectly fine."* Sure -- but it won't be the state you just set. *"...I have to use a callback function..."* You do *if* you're basing the new state on the existing state, because you cannot use `this.state` directly in a `this.setState()` call. So this is fine: `this.setState({foo: 42});` This is **not**: `this.setState({foo: this.state.foo + 1});` Instead, you'd need the callback form: `this.setState(prevState => return {foo: prevState + 1};);` So if you're just setting `{cols_of_sel_tab: parsedData}`, you don't.

Comment: Yes, I get that! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**1. Solution to your question**

The main problem why you (somehow without syntax error and not getting the empty state problem) get the

*Output:{table_cols: Array(3)} WOW*

and not the array items, because of the model of your response

```
[
  {"table_cols":
      ["id",
      "stud_name",
      "stud_school"]
  }
]
```

So, instead of

```
let cols = this.state.cols_of_sel_tab[i]
```

should be

```
let cols = this.state.cols_of_sel_tab[i].table_cols
```

And input will be:
*{table_cols: Array(3)}
WOW
id
stud_name
stud_school*

**2. Syntax Error**

```
cols = [];
let cols = this.state.cols_of_sel_tab[i]
```

You're trying to assign empty array to the variable, that not defined.
In this particular example you could just amend the first row

**3. State handling**

In your code example you've got two goals: update the state with new data and use the new data for output. Cause state updates are asynchronous is much safer to manipulate and output the data you already have right away (I amended debug console output).

```
this.setState({cols_of_sel_tab: parsedData})
for(let i=0; i<parsedData.length; i++) {
    let cols = parsedData.cols_of_sel_tab[i].table_cols
    for (let j = 0; j<cols.length; j++) {
        console.log(cols[j])
    }
}
```

Also, cause [states updates are merged](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged) you can amend spread operator for this.state, like in the code above.

**4.More improvements**

1. There is a map function mention in header of the question, you could use it.

   ```
   parsedData.map(
       col_of_sel => col_of_sel.table_cols.map(
           cols => console.log(cols)
       )
   )
   ```

   or, if you only need the table_cols of the first object:

   ```
   parsedData[0].table_cols.map(cols => console.log(cols))
   ```
2. You've got different code style in your example in question: semicolon presence, differences in indentations. I recommend to use some kind of [prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier) to pretty up the code, so it will be easier to read.

**Finally**

```
let parsedData = JSON.parse(resp._bodyText)
this.setState({ cols_of_sel_tab: parsedData })
parsedData[0].table_cols.map(cols => console.log(cols))
```

Comment: The map function works perfect! also with `this.state.cols_of_sel_tab` instead of parsedData. <br/> However, the for loop gives an exception: `Unhandled Promise Rejection: Type Error: Cannot read property 0 of undefined`.<br/> I edited the for loop, with state variable and iterating on it's length and it gave me the desired output. Thanks!

Comment: I am also working on prettying up the code! Thanks for the clear explanation and patience!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a slight misunderstanding of what your JSON data represents.

If we make the JSON a little prettier:

```
[
    {"table_cols":
        ["id",
        "stud_name",
        "stud_school"]
    }
]
```

The outer square brackets represent an `array`. This `array` contains one item at index `0`, which is the `table_cols` object. This object also contains an `array`, with your table col fields in.

You're running a `for` loop on the outer array. The first item this loop will come across is the object at index `0`. To reach the table columns you'd need to either run a second `for` loop on the table_cols, or run the original loop on `this.state.cols_of_sel_tab[0].table_cols`.